#  Ajax functions like .load() strip out comments from the HTML. How can I keep the comments?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

For example, `$('#some-div').load('http://foo.bar #content')` will retrieve `#content` from http://foo.bar but with all HTML `<!--comments-->` stripped.

How can I retrieve the contents of `#content` *including* any comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/load):

> jQuery uses the browser's `.innerHTML` property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`, or `<head>` elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by `.load()` may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

So you should use `$.get()` to retrieve the HTML instead of `$.fn.load()`

Comment: Part of your answer was filtered out. If you put a space after "<" i'll understand. Can you add those parts? Anyways, according to the jQuery API reference, .get() is called like this: `.get( [ index ] )`... There is no ability implemented with it to grab contents from other locations (URLs).

Comment: The $.get() I'm referring to is http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get As for the format of the answer it looks good to me. The last line is of my own not from JQuery's doc.

Comment: Oh cool. I'm taking your word for it. ;) I'll try it out soon. :)